# Drawing stones on the board for Android Go game App

Tags: android, drawing, 2d, baduk

I am an Android Newbie and I'm developing Go game application for android. 
I'm having a problem with drawing single stone on my board.
Here is my onDraw() method.

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
   //drawing a board
   //...
   //...

     canvas.drawBitmap(stone_image, stoneX - (stone_image.getWidth() / 2), stoneY
     - (stone_image.getHeight() / 2),paint);
}
```

And I have an onTouch() method:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    stoneX = (int) event.getX();
    stoneY = (int) event.getY();
    return true;
}
```

The point is, when I set background color in my class constuctor using this method:

```
setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Application can't draw a stone on the board after a touchEvent, but when I don't set a background color, application draws a stone perfectly.
P.S. Attributes stoneX,stoneY are correctly defined and initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what View you are using, but I know that there is some problems when using a `SurfaceView` with a background (could be the case for other views too?) where the background draws on top so you only get a background.

*Instead* of setting the background color with `setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)`, you should start your `onDraw()` with `canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE)`.

Comment: I'm using a SurfaceView. Thanx your advice worked!  P.S. What should I do, to set the background image?

Comment: You are welcome, remember to mark the question as answered :)
To use a background image, you can replace the drawColor with a drawBitmap and draw an image that way, or if you have a drawable, you would call it's draw() from your onDraw.